# Unable to SSH IPV6 vps (Hetzner + AlmaLinux + Virtualizor)

Tags: ipv6, hetzner

I have a Hetzner dedicated server with 1 ipv4 address and 1 ipv6 subnet. The aim is to run VPSs with ipv6s.

OS: AlmaLinux 8 + Virtualizor on it.

My ipv6 subnet:

```
2a01:4f8:171:1cd3:: / 64
```

Opened /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and (according to Hetzner's instruction added):

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=eth0
```

---

In Virtualizor created an ip pool, ipv6 subnet and generated a bunch of ipv6s:

[ipv6 addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb3m5.png)

---

Created a vps (ubuntu 18.04), and everything looks fine:

ipv6s:

```
2a01:4f8:171:1cd3:abcd:11:02cd:d3e0

2a01:4f8:171:1cd3:abcd:11:06d1:7f33
```

[2 vpss ready](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owSVk.png)

---

Putty fails to connect to ipv6 (Network Error. Network Unreachable):

Ssh-ed into the whole server using its ipv4.

Ran:
ip -6 addr

result:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: viifbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::2/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3497:85ff:fee2:c1ee/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: viifv1001: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::fc16:3eff:fe34:ecaa/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: viifv1002: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::fc16:3eff:fec7:81aa/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

--

then:

```
ip -6 addr show scope global
```

result:

```
4: viifbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::2/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

--

```
ip addr | grep inet6
```

result:

```
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
inet6 2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::2/64 scope global
inet6 fe80::3497:85ff:fee2:c1ee/64 scope link
inet6 fe80::fc16:3eff:fe34:ecaa/64 scope link
inet6 fe80::fc16:3eff:fec7:81aa/64 scope link
```

--

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

Result:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

--

Shall I add those ipv6s individually like Hetzner says that optionally to the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 we can add ipv6s manually (separated each by space):

```
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES=<IPv6 Address>/<Prefix>
```

--

Tried ssh access from Vrtualizor's terminal > failed (SSh will only work if java is installed and enabled)

Enabled vnc on the 2nd > "failed to connect to server"

--

So stuck..

What I am missing?

Looking for direction and, hopefully, a solution. Thank you

---

Update 1

was

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=eth0
```

testing (added '2' to IPV6ADDR, and added IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES):

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::2/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=eth0
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES=2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::3 2a01:4f8:171:1cd3::4/64
```

Comment: Does outgoing traffic work? What does IP -6 route show? (Update your question with this info)

Comment: Is the sshd port even listening, check with `sudo ss -tulpn | grep ssh`

Answer (score 0):

as per https://docs.hetzner.com/cloud/servers/getting-started/connecting-to-the-server/

if the IPv6 address displayed in your hetzner dashboard is like 2a01:2001:db8:1234::/64, then the way we ssh in is by replacing `/64` with `1`

A full command including a specific private ssh key file specified and telling the system to not bother trying the other ssh keys:

```
ssh -6 -i ~/.ssh/keys/hetzner-key -o IdentitiesOnly=yes root@2a01:2001:db8:1234::1
```

in case you have a different user from root then replace `root` above with that username.